# NotAuthenticateException invoking SOAP webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to use a SOAP Webservice (code in Java) from ColdFusion 9.

```
<cfset ps = CreateObject("webservice", "MySoapService")>    
<cfscript>  
    ps.login('me@example.com', 'password');
    ps.sendEmail('sendto@example.com');
</cfscript>
```

I use this SOAP webservice in java projects, and it works well. The login process works well, but with the sendEmail process, I am getting a NotAuthenticateException.

I'm not used to working with CF. Is it possible the object is reset between the login and the sendEmail process?

Comment: *The login process works well* How are you determining that? Based on the error message it does not sound like the login is successful. Hard to say without more details about the WS. Is the url public?

Comment: during the login, the process create a sessionId, but in the sendEmail, the sessionId returns NULL.

Comment: The code above does not reference a session id. It is hard to suggest anything without more information about the web service and how this session id fits into the picture? Can you please post either a public URL or the relevant sections of the web service?